# trying to add extra field using hooks

Tags: custom-field, actions, child-theme

I am trying to add an extra field on the backend menu of

> Edit Subscription menu (SUMO Subscription (plugin) -> List of
>   Subscription -> Edit Subscription)

I am sending you a screenshot for where exactly I would like to add it.
[image]

```
do_action( 'sumosubscriptions_admin_after_general_details' , $post->ID );

// 10 is the priority, higher means executed first
// 1 is number of arguments the function can accept
add_action('sumosubscriptions_admin_after_general_details', 'custom_domain', 10, 1);
function custom_domain($post) {
    // do something
    <input type="text" name="Domain" value="<?php echo $name;?>">
}
```

I know it's possibly an easy one problem but I haven't succeed to find a solution.
Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not familiar with the subscription plugin you're using. But as you're attaching a custom function to a action hook, you should most likely echo or print the html you want to be displayed at that particular point. Like this,

```
function custom_domain( $post_id ) {
  // if this is saved as post_meta then get it with get_post_meta( $post_id, 'some_meta_key', true );
  $domain = 'someurl.com'; 
  printf(
    '<input type="text" name="Domain" value="%s">',
    esc_url( $domain )
  );
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the feedback. It worked just like i wanted!